# How to wrap to a single object in a tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not exactly sure how to word this question, so sorry in advance for any confusion. I need to wrap (or some sort of equivalent) a single object into a tree of objects.

The HTML of what is being wrapped:

```html
<div class="border-wrapper">
  <div class="topbar"></div>
  <div class="border-shell">
    <div class="border-inside">ELEMENT THAT WILL BE WRAPPED SHOULD END UP HERE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Originally I tried to do:

```
$(obj).wrap('<div class="border-wrapper"><div class="topbar"></div><div class="border-shell"><div class="border-inside"></div></div></div>');
```

But it would wrap the object into `.topbar`.

Then I tried to wrap without `.topbar` and prepend it later, but nothing would prepend. My attempt with `before()` didn't work either.

I have even tried using multiple wraps (wrap .border-inside & .border-shell around the element, then insert the `.topbar` and `.wrapAll()`) but nothing seemed to work. My guess is that it's all firing in parallel instead of in sequence.

Modified below to add a below/after:

Before:

```
<span>test</span>
```

After:

```html
<div class="border-wrapper">
  <div class="topbar"></div>
  <div class="border-shell">
    <div class="border-inside"><span>test</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear to me. Can you post the `before` and `after` of what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything on the wrap documentation page that says it can handle multiple tags and elements..

just as a test have you tried:

```
$(obj).wrap('<div class="border-inside"></div>').wrap('<div class="border-wrapper"></div>');
```

to see what it does

Comment: Doh. I was able to solve it using `$(obj).wrap('<div class="border-wrapper" />').wrap('<div class="border-shell"><div class="border-inside"></div></div>').parent().parent().parent().prepend('<div class="border-topbar" />');` I can't help but wonder if there's a more elegant solution, but this is working!

Comment: well you could always extend jquery with your own method to make it neat ;-) 

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 1):

This is hacky - but could you could do something like this -

**HTML**

```
<span class="inner">ELEMENT THAT WILL BE WRAPPED SHOULD END UP HERE</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
var elemhtml = $(".inner").clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
$(".inner").html('<div class="border-wrapper"><div class="topbar"></div><div class="border-shell"><div class="border-inside">' + elemhtml + '</div></div></div>');
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Apc8c/